# Regex - String contains 6 digits

Tags: regex, validation

I'm trying to write a regex to parse a bank sort code from a database. 
The reason I need a regex is that the sort code might be contained in a sentence.
But also, it might not be a sort code at all because the people entering data into the database some times put bank account numbers and phone numbers into the sort code column.
I can use

```
^[^0-9]*[0-9]{6}[^\d]*$
```

which works on

```
"blah123456blah"
```

but not on

```
"Emloyee 12's srt code : 123456"
```

Anything else I've tried gives me a match for 6 *or more* digits within a string (which is then most likely a bank account number).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try using [`(^|[^0-9])[0-9]{6}([^0-9]|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/4oHD8c/1)? Or should there be only 1 chunk of six digits in the string? Also, is the pattern anchored by default? What is the language/tool?

Comment: What if they've entered dashes in the sort code like a lot of people do in the UK - 20-03-84 for instance

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you want. Can you put on separate lines a few examples that should match and some that it shouldn't match?

Comment: I tried these ideas but the problem is that while they match "123456" they also match "12345678", which I don't want.

Comment: @Shanie: [`(^|[^0-9])[0-9]{6}([^0-9]|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/4oHD8c/2) does not match that string.

Comment: @Chris The example I gave is a simplified version of what I'm doing. This is what I'm actually using: [0-9]{2}\s*-?\s*[0-9]{2}\s*-?\s*[0-9]{2}. The problem remains the same though. It matches more than 6 digits.

Comment: Add `(^|[^0-9])` before and  `([^0-9]|$)` after.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yeah, that seems to work perfectly. What does the '|' mean in a regex?

Comment: The `|` is an *alternation operator*.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You're a hero! Thanks to everyone for their help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you are using

```
[0-9]{2}\s*-?\s*[0-9]{2}\s*-?\s*[0-9]{2}
```

To add the boundaries like you need, add `(^|[^0-9])` (either the string start position (`^`) or (`|`) a non-digit (`[^0-9]`)) in front and  `([^0-9]|$)` (matching a non-digit or the end of string position (`$`)) at the end:

```
(^|[^0-9])[0-9]{2}\s*-?\s*[0-9]{2}\s*-?\s*[0-9]{2}([^0-9]|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4oHD8c/3).